# can an EMF Ecore EReference own properties

Tags: modeling, uml, eclipse-emf-ecore

I would like to make an ORM Entity metamodel and to be able to manipulate an instance (model) using a diagram representation (I am using "Obeo designer" software).

The entity EClass have a reference on itself to represent relationship between different entities. Is there a way to associate properties on the relationship in order to modelise its properties (like type, fetchtype, cascade, orphan removal, etc...)

Otherwise what would be the best way to modelise a relationship between 2 entities ?

Comment: Just a precision, i know that it already exists tools like this one http://marketplace.obeonetwork.com/module/entity#. I'am just making POC of e-core modeling and exploitation

Answer (score 0):

you can check **proprities** in eclipse like :upperBound, containement,....